# Python stdout, \r progress bar and sshd with Putty not updating regularly

Tags: python, ssh, putty

I have a dead simple progress "bar" using something like the following:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

current = 0
limit = 50
while current <= limit:
    sys.stdout.write('\rSynced %s/%s orders' % (current, limit))
    current_order += 1
    sleep(1)
```

Works fine, except over ssh with Putty. Putty only updates every 3 minutes or if a line ends with \n. Is this a Putty setting, sshd_config, or can I code around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing `sys.stdout.flush()` after `sys.stdout.write` call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flush()` to force an update.

```
sys.stdout.write('\r[%s%s]' % ('=' * completed, ' ' * (total-completed)))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sys.stderr.write` instead, which is not buffered as `sys.stdout` is, and this way you separate progress indicator from the (presumably) useful process output.